# Java how to save expression?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Java how to save expression with a variable or database?I want guess game can auto judge result by expression.
such as a price predict game,when stock closed, today close > today open,side A is winner or side B is winner.In this case,I want a variable or db can save expression like below:(close and open are Double,at the beginning,close is null)

```
side a;
a.expression="close>open";
```

when stock close,I need it auto:

```
game.open=3000;
game.close=4000;
boolean isWinner=autoJudge(a.expression);//I want it return true
```

How to do it in SpringBoot by using java?Thank you.

Comment: to save expressions check "Java8 Lambda expressions". In your case you could try: a.setExpression((close,open) -> close > open) while expression is of type BiPredicate<Integer, Integer>

Comment: @ndueck But I have a hard time seeing how you could save such a lambda expression into a database ...

Comment: I hope all type guess game can extend Game.class and autoJudge before ask this question,maybe it's wrong,I will divide the different games in different implementation class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disting non-answer: don't even try.

Besides the enormous challenges to persist **code** within your database in a reliable and robust way, that is simply a *bad* idea.

Databases store **data**, not code (they are called *database*, not *codebase*). If your game has to make **decisions** based on database content, then that decision making should go **into** your code.